# ng-repeat with ng-click function if else Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, class, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

When you click one of addOn's, in ng-class="{{sectionClass}}", I would like to add a class to the element.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

My way is not working, and I am not sure what is wrong with the code.

```js
            $scope.addOns = [
              
             {                        
                    name: "Cover options"
                },
                {
                    name: "Stamping"
                }
            ];

            $scope.sectionClass = function(addOn){

             if (addOn.name == "Cover options")

              return("covers");

             else if (addOn.name == "Stamping")

              return("stamping");

            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-content" ng-class="{{sectionClass}}"> 
    <div class="add-on-type" ng-click="sectionClass(addOns)" ng-repeat="addOn in addOns">
        <span>{{addOn.name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What? I don't understand. Can you explain more please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed couple of thing

1. Pass `addon` object from `ng-repeat` `ng-click` function like `ng-click="sectionClass(addOn)"`
2. Don't return a string from method instead set one scope variable like `customClass` & use it in `ng-class` directive

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" >
    <div class="section-content" ng-class="{{customClass}}">
        <div class="add-on-type" ng-click="sectionClass(addOn)" ng-repeat="addOn in addOns"> <span>{{addOn.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.addOns = [

    {
        name: "Cover options"
    }, {
        name: "Stamping"
    }];

    $scope.sectionClass = function (addOn) {
        if (addOn.name == "Cover options")
            $scope.customClass="covers"

        else if (addOn.name == "Stamping")
            $scope.customClass="stamping"    
    }
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/6159/)

Hope this could help you. Thanks.